# several changes to DOM in the same browser tick cycle

Tags: javascript, dom

If I add an element to the DOM, are the changes immediate? If I remove the same element in the next line of my code, will the element appear on the screen (for a short period of time)? Or does the display get updated when the current browser cycle ends?

Comment: no it won't show, the processing cycle is in micro seconds. you couldn't able to see

Comment: _"will the element appear on the screen (for a short period of time)?"_  The element should appear in `DOM`. Not certain about on screen. Could depend on how frequently monitor is updated

Comment: @akonsu What are you specifically trying to determine? The visiblity of the element apparent to human vision? Or the event of element being added to and removed from `DOM`?

Comment: I need to measure an element, so I attach it to DOM, and it is available immediately, and I can get the styles right away. I am trying to figure out if I need to worry about the element appearing on the screen when I do that and whether I need to attach it to a fragment that is not visible or if I can forget this issue because the element won't render anyway.

Comment: @akonsu The element will probably not be apparently visible to human vision. Though, as you suggested, appending the element to an element container where `display` is set to `none` should provide greater assurance that element is not visible. Using a document fragment that is not appended to `DOM` should also provide expected result. You could probably measure the total time the element is in document, if appended to `DOM`, to determine if it is possible to see element with human vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously appearance of elements depends on the power of CPU, browser algorithms, graphic card render time, monitor frequency and many other factors. However The programs (e.g JavaScript) may continue the actions by considering virtual elements without errors.

On the other hand the browser algorithm may decide to render the code line by line or not. As an experience if you run a heavy loop to append items to the body, the Opera browser displays the items one by one however the Chrome will render the page at the end of loop. However if you do the loop using the JavaScript **setTimeout**, in all browsers you will see the elements appearing one by one.

Comment: I do not agree with the statement about the power of CPU and the graphics card rendering time (because if the browser simply does not render the screen until the end of the cycle then it does not matter how fast the CPU, etc is), but otherwise this is reasonable to assume that there are different approaches to rendering in different browsers. Thank you. `setTimeout` is outside of this question because it spans several browser cycles.

Answer (score 4):

It will NEVER show no matter how fast your machine is. Javascript will run to completion blocking the UI until its done.

Try this

HTML

```
<div id='d'></div>
```

JS

```
var d = document.getElementById('d');
var p = document.createElement('p');

p.innerText = "One";
d.appendChild(p);

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  for (z = 0; z < 10; z++){
    // this is nonsense that runs for a sec or two to block the JS thread
    // please never do this in production
  }
}

p.innerText = "Two"
```

will pause your browser and then show `Two` ... never `One`

Comment: Do you know if this is true for all browsers? Mobile too?

Comment: I believe so. All JS environments